# Selenium script to download file on headless mode

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

**This is not a duplicate. I want to achieve this on a headless linux server. No GUI, no browser profile file. I need to set profile preferences in code.**

My goal: download an image file generated by a .php + .js script using python selenium firefox on full headless mode.

My issue:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/home/ubuntu")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/png")

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.profile = profile

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://old.ferramentas.eucreio.org/citacao/")

print(driver.title)

driver.close()
```

returns:

```
get_assets.py:6: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object
  profile = FirefoxProfile()
get_assets.py:14: DeprecationWarning: Setting a profile has been deprecated. Please use the set_preference and install_addons methods
  options.profile = profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_assets.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 179, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Connection refused (os error 111)
```

If I sneak a `options.set_preference()` (instead of using the `FirefoxProfile` instance) in there it doesn't work either. Also trying to set `firefox_profile` as `webdriver.Firefox()` parameter has no different outcome.. just says everything is deprecated.

I'm having such a headache with this.. just feel something is so off here and I can't say what.

I've also exhausted the entire internet looking for a code that shed some light on this and.. just nothing.

The internet page is set to download the image as soon as it loads. And all I want is a headless download

Someone with some more experience could help me please?

Comment: As said, the image file is generated "on the run", on a .php + .js script, it's not available directly on an url :/

Comment: With `TimeoutException: Message: Connection refused`, are you sure you have internet connection ?

Comment: @Philippe I've only been testing this through SSH, on the headless server itself.

Comment: I know. I'm asking if you have internet connection on that headless server. Can you try `curl https://www.google.com` ?

Comment: Yea, it works..